# Trigger cascade DELETE without deleting record

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I would like to perform a sort of factory reset of a User record. Is there some way of triggering the cascading delete without actually deleting the user record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the record to a temporary table, delete the original record, then copy the record back from the temporary.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempUser
AS SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = :idToReset;

DELETE FROM User WHERE id = :idToReset;

INSERT INTO User
SELECT * FROM tempUser;
```

Comment: This seems to be a great solution. I live on the API/front-end world and the concept of a temporary table slipped my mind. I think that I'll put this into a stored proc and execute it with a single RESTful call.  Thanks for the help!